# Extending periodic piecewise continuous function

Tags: piecewise, periodic-function

I need to plot the piecewise function

$$
f(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
x^2, & -2 \leq x \leq 0, \\ 
0, & 0 < x \leq 1, \\
1 - x, & 1 < x \leq 3. \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

as a periodic function on an extended interval. The duplication of the like problem I see here seems to be working only for that specific case

```
f1[y_] := f[Mod[y, 4]]
Plot[f1[x], {x, -8, 8}]
```

Comment: Please clarify which function you want to plot.

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand exactly what your function is; you may want to try something along these lines:

```
X := Mod[x, 4];
f[x_] := Piecewise[{
   {0, X <= 1},
   {1 - X, 1 <= X <= 3},
   {X^2, X <= 4}
   }]
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this work well, Please let me know the function of X := Mod[x, 4]; in this code

Comment: It is just a replacement to avoid typing `Mod[x, 4]` several times. You can read the documentation of `SetDelayed`.